# How to set field value based on what user click in Django ListView

Tags: django

I have two models `Parent` and `Child`. I would like to display both values in a `ListView`, whereby there is an `Add Child` button for each family.

Supposed that the parents are already populated, when I click `Add Child`, I would love that in the form of Child, the parent field are already set to the corresponding family name (please see code below).

Simple model would be:

```
class Family(models.Model):
    family_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=False)
    father_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default='')
    mother_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default='')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('family-list')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.family_name)


class Children(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Family, blank=False, default=None, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='their_child')
    child_name = models.CharField('4Jet ID', max_length=100, default='', blank=False)
    birth_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, blank=False)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('family-list') # both return to family list view
```

The View using simple generic view:

```
class FamilyList(ListView):
    model = Family
    template_name = '/family_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'fam_list'

# class NewParent omitted

class NewChild(CreateView):
    model = Children
    template_name = '/child_new.html'
    context_object_name = 'child'
    fields = [
        'parent', 'child_name', 'birth_date'
    ]
```

and the simplified template:

```
<!--file: family_list.html-->
{% for fam in fam_list %}

<table>
    <tr>
        <th class="header"></th>
        <th class="header">Family Name</th>
        <th class="header">Father's First Name</th>
        <th class="header">Mother's First Name</th>
        <th class="header">Add Child</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>+</td>
        <td>{{ fam.family_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ fam.father_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ fam.versand_datum | date:"d M, Y" }}</td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'new-child' %}" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Add Child</a>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr >
        <td colspan="5">
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="header">Child's First Name</th>
                        <th class="header">Date of Birth</th>
                    </tr>
                    {% for child in fam.their_child.all %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ child.child_name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ child.birth_date | date:"d M, Y" }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </table>

            </div>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

{% endfor %}
```

---

I've tried playing with the `get_initial` method in the `NewChild` view but by setting pdb trace within the method, the `self.request.GET.getlist()` gives me empty list.

Again, I just want that when I click the `Add Child` button in the template, the `parent` field in the child form will be set corresponding to the parent that I clicked.

Any idea how to do that?

All help are much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your template is only a template to wiew a result, not to record an other one. 
You must write a form and the most simple to you is to follow the initial Django tutorial.

Url : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial04/

You need :
- write a form template
- write a service to record you form result.
- and write a new template to view your record.

Take the time to do the initial tutorial, it is simple to follow

Comment: Well, I do have the Child recording template, but it's just the <form> with post method and a submit input, which I don't think is correlated. Or is it?

And the result are shown directly to the family_list.html

Comment: I guess I thought to complicated and asked the question in a wrong way.

Manage to do it with just passing the url, and take it as another view argument with `get_initial` function.

Anyway, thanks @marcS